# Cannot set width in qweb

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qwebview, qweb

```
<div class="row" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <table class="table table-condensed" >
        <thead style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left" width="5%" style="border-left:1px solid black;">Sl no</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left:1px solid black;">Account</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left:1px solid black;">Partner</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left:1px solid black;">Internal Reference</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left:1px solid black;">Description</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left:1px solid black;">Debit Amount(AED)</th>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left:1px solid black;">Credit Amount(AED)</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
            <t t-set="count" t-value="1"/>
            <tr t-foreach="o.line_ids" t-as="l" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <td  class="text-left" width="5%"><span t-esc="count"/> <t t-set="count" t-value="count + 1"/></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="border-left:1px solid black;"><span t-field="l.account_id.name"/></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="border-left:1px solid black;"><span t-field="l.partner_id"/></td>
                <td class="text-left" style="border-left:1px solid black;"><span t-field="l.account_id.code"/></td>
                <td  class="text-left" style="border-left:1px solid black;"><span t-field="l.name"/></td>
                <td  class="text-right" style="border-left:1px solid black;"><span t-field="l.debit"/></td>
                <td  class="text-right" style="border-left:1px solid black;"><span t-field="l.credit"/></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
    <td style="display:inline;border-left:1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;">
        <span t-if="o.ref">
        <span>Reference:</span><span><span   t-field="o.ref"/></span>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;">
    </td>
    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;">
    </td>
    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;">
    </td>
    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;">
    </td>
    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;">
    </td>
    <td style="border-top:1px solid black;">
    </td>
</tr>

        </tbody>                            
    </table>
 </div>
```

Hi above is my xml code . Problem I face is that I cannot set a width for the column `Sl No` I tried by putting `width="5%"` in `th` and `td` and I also tried putting it in `style` like `style="width:5%"` but that also does n't work. Please Help .
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of `th` will be set correctly. The issue should be in the value of width, `5%` is maybe not enough to show `Sl No` on the same line.

Try

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="7" style="display:inline;border-left:1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;">
        <span t-if="o.ref">
            <span>Reference:</span><span><span t-field="o.ref"/></span>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: So how much % will you recommend ? @zety

Comment: 7% should be enough.

Comment: a new <tr> is added .. Is it because of that ?

Comment: No, `width` can affect the number of rows.

Comment: The number of rows should be the number of lines + 1 (the last row outside the loop).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170674/discussion-between-vbt-and-zety).